# negate floating number in c fails in some cases

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I wrote a function which works for hundreds of cases but fails in some cases.

Here is the C function:

```
unsigned negate_number(unsigned x) {
  int sign = (!(x & 0x80000000))<<31;
  int other = 0x7FFFFFFF & x;
  return (sign | other);
}
```

I am just masking sign, inverting it and doing a OR (joining) with masked exponent and mantessa. So this should work in all cases.

But here is a case where it fails:
x = 0x7fc00000 (2143289344)

Comment: Why are you asking about 'floating number' in the title when the code is working with integers?  Are you trying to call the function with a `float` and treat it as an array of bits, more or less?  If so, you're on a hiding to nothing!  If you call the function with a prototype in scope, the C compiler will convert the `float` to an `unsigned int`.  If you don't call it with a prototype in scope, the C compiler will convert the `float` to a `double` before calling the function.

Comment: It is a 32 bit IEEE 754 single precision number. So I am just flipping the most significant bit (sign bit).

Comment: This fails for NaN (not a number) inputs. How can it be made fail-safe for these cases?

Comment: @Anon if you complement the sign of a NaN, it's still a NaN - unless other code is broken and fails to detect that kind of NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I asked:

> Why are you asking about 'floating number' in the title when the code is working with integers? Are you trying to call the function with a `float` and treat it as an array of bits, more or less? If so, you're on a hiding to nothing! If you call the function with a prototype in scope, the C compiler will convert the `float` to an `unsigned int`. If you don't call it with a prototype in scope, the C compiler will convert the `float` to a `double` before calling the function.

And the response was:

> It is a 32 bit IEEE 754 single precision number. So I am just flipping the most significant bit (sign bit).

To flip the most significant bit of a 32-bit (unsigned integer) quantity, you could simply write:

```
x ^= 0x80000000;
```

However, as I indicated, you are simply not getting passed a 32-bit `float` unless you are lying to your compiler.  You could 'get it to work' (on some machines, some of the time) if you had:

### Bogus Code

#### fileA.c

```
extern float negate_number(float x);

...
float f1 = 3.14159;
float f2 = negate_number(f1);
...
```

#### fileB.c

```
unsigned negate_number(unsigned x)
{
    return x ^ 0x80000000;
}
```

However, you are playing with fire and fibbing to your compiler.  Compilers hate being lied to and often find a way to get their own back.  **Do Not Do This!**

### Mostly kosher code

To achieve more or less the effect you want with a minimum of issues (but not 'no issues'), you probably need:

#### fileB.c

```
float negate_number(float f)
{
    union { unsigned x; float y; } u;
    u.y = f;
    u.x ^= 0x80000000;
    return u.y;
}
```

Strictly, reading and writing to `u.x` after assigning to `u.y` is undefined behaviour, but it will normally do what you want; similarly with returning `u.y` after manipulating `u.x`.

All of this assumes that the bit layout of `float` and `unsigned` are such that the sign bit of the `float` is the most significant bit of the `unsigned`.

Comment: I cannot use float as the type. I have to work with unsigned int as the type. But the input will be a 32-bit single precision floating point number (IEEE 754).

Comment: You are not understanding what I write. The input to the function cannot be a 32-bit `float`. You can do the `union` stuff out in the calling code and pass `u.x` to your function. Or you can do the `union` stuff in `negate_number()`.  But you can't do it the way your code is written.  (Or, at the very least, I don't think you can do it the way your code is written.)  [...to be continued...]

Comment: [...continuing...] Now, if you have an `unsigned` in your calling code that contains the bit pattern corresponding to some `float` value, then of course you may pass that `unsigned int` to the function with the `unsigned` argument and `unsigned` return value, and then you can use the version of `negate_number()` marked as 'Bogus'.  But you should be clear that you are passing an `unsigned` (that happens to contain the same bit pattern as some `float`) and not a `float` per se.

Comment: Yes, the inputs are unsigned ints thats contain some corresponding float values including Nan(not a number) which need to be returned if the are thrown as input.

Comment: OK; so you are passing `unsigned` values around.  You should be much clearer in your question!  According to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), you can flip the sign bit of a NaN without really affecting it.  If you don't want to attempt (or risk) changing a NaN, detect the NaN pattern `((x & 0x7F100000) == 0x7F100000)` and leave the value unchanged.

Comment: found a better solution: checking if mantessa = 255 (Nan case) and handling infinity seperately. works now!

Comment: OK, but according to Wikipedia, 'mantissa = 127' is also a NaN.