# Reinterpreting an unsigned int to a float in C++

Tags: c++, casting, int

I have a float representation stored in an unsigned __int32. I know that you can reconstruct the number byte shifting, just as instructed in the answer of this question:

[Convert int to float in C (no casting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344400/convert-int-to-float-in-c-no-casting)

I want to avoid the shifting, multiplications and sums and just reinterpret the bits. I tried the Wikipedia example for IEEE 754 single precision entry but the reinterpretation results in a 0.

Here's my code:

```
unsigned __int32 integer = 0;   
unsigned __int32 mask = 0;
mask = mask + 1 << 30;
mask = mask + 1 << 29;
mask = mask + 1 << 28;
mask = mask + 1 << 27;
mask = mask + 1 << 26;
mask = mask + 1 << 22;
integer = integer ^ mask;
printf("%ld %d\n", integer, sizeof(__int32));
float* decimal = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&integer);
printf("%f", *decimal);
return 0;
```

Comment: Try printing out the `mask` to verify it is what you expect it to be, and then read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: That looks roughly how I would try to do what you say.  What CPU are you working against here?  Various assemblers do this in different ways (store int; load float; convert direct; etc.)  Looking at the assembler output here in a debugger should give you a clue on what is going wrong here.

Comment: Ah, use parenthesis or mask all you bits at once is what @Praetorian is wisely suggesting.  :)

Comment: Reinterpreting the bits is exactly what your `reinterpret_cast` is doing.  I'm confused as to what it is you actually want to achieve.

Comment: btw, you can do `float decimal = reinterpret_cast<float&>(integer);` --- no need for pointers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Pretorian, not the main issue, but certaintly it was also wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem here is that you're violating the strict alias rules by having two differently typed (non-char) pointers point to the same memory location.

The simplest, most straightforward solution to your problem is just to `memcpy` the bytes (after asserting that the size of your integer and float types are the same):

```
float decimal = 0.0f;
memcpy(&decimal, &integer, sizeof(integer));
```